# I want to use a specific Cocos2d library in a non-Cocos2d project

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, scenekit

friends! I'm relatively new to iOS development, and am working on a game with a friend. The friend did the majority of the programming, but I'm helping him finish it (he's really busy), so I have a few gaps in my knowledge. I'm trying to implement a new feature (essentially pausing the game, but in a specific way), and doing so will create a lot of complication regarding the use of performSelector:afterDelay. I have searched for a solution online, and it seems the best thing to do is to use cocos2d's "schedule" function instead of performSelector, as it is much more robust.

SO HERE'S MY QUESTION: the game currently does not use Cocos2d in any way; it uses SceneKit, lua, and a lot of custom stuff, too. **What is the simplest way to make use of this specific aspect of Cocos2d without having to make a "Cocos2d Project"** or whatever? I've seen some tutorials here and there but frankly they all seem contradictory and/or confusing! I'm hoping it is as simple as adding a library to xCode and then linking it with my existing project, something I certainly know how to do in other languages/environments but can't quite figure out here. I hope I worded this specifically enough for it to be a good question!

Comment: Using Cocos2d in order to fix a problem with `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` is absurd, like killing a gnat with a bazooka. This sounds like an X/Y problem. Why not talk about your specific problem and ask for help in solving it?

Comment: Hmm... I've thought of that, but the main problem is just that I want to be able to pause all selector timers and unpause them, and Cocos2d provides an incredibly simple way to do that! The alternative, as far as I can tell, would be to add a bunch of variables and also a dictionary. I can probably figure it out but it'd be a huge pain. So I want to just link just a portion of the library (so, instead of the whole bazooka, just the important part), since cocos2d seems to be a collection of libraries, not a single monolithic system. Does that make more sense, or am I still on the wrong track?

Comment: There is no built-in mechanism I'm aware of to pause timers or pause pending performSelector calls. If you have code written using `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay` that you want to be able to pause, you'll have to refactor your code to do it the cocos2d way anyway. I have almost no experience with cocos, but since it's an open source library perhaps you could study the mechanism and implement something like it in your code.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification! I'll dig around, and I'll come back and either reply/update my question or mark it as answered later.

Comment: The pause is a side-effect of the cocos2d library construction and integration in the Display Link. Adding it to a foreign code base will not help. In fact, you can still use `performSelector` within any coco2ds class or extension ... but ... doing so will most likely break the `pause` feature. I would follow @DuncanC 's advice if in a hurry, or wait for apple's `SK` team to come up with yet another great idea : pause. After all, they have borrowed every other idea from the open sources libraries like cocos2d, it is just a matter of time :)  ... best of luck with your project.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg, I wondered if cocos2d used displayLink for it's "pausable" timers. That makes sense, since it's a reliable timer that runs at the device frame-rate. So pausing in Cocos2d pauses the displayLink? Doesn't that mean that you can't update the cocos2d display at all while paused?

Comment: Thanks to both of you, @YvesLeBorg and duncanc (i can't @ both of u sorry)! I did a bit more research based on both of your comments and have decided on a course of action. I don't have enough rep to upvote your comments but would be glad to do so if you reposted them as answers instead!

Comment: @DuncanC I'd have to go look. I dont use the cocos2d `pause` anyways, precisely for considerations such as OP's question. I have my own persistence strategy than permits me to be able to stop/resume on any logical step in a game, thus for me 'pause' is just a 'persist' - 'wait' -'reload' , so i can still have the draw call during of the run-loop during the pause. But since you can still have 'buttons' during pause, i suspect that `pause` merely slips the run-loop for timers, animations and the like, but keeps the draw and touch processing.